# Unable to create_context using teradataml due to OperationalError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'm using teradataml package version 16.20.0.4 and I get a strange error during the creation of the context, using the usual

```py
import teradataml as tdml    
tdml.create_context(username = 'user', password='pass', host='host')
```

Then I get

```
[...]

OperationalError: (teradatasql.OperationalError) [Version 16.20.0.59] [Session 6751033] [Teradata Database] [Error 3706] Syntax error: expected something between ')' and ','.
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).formatDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1102
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeChainedDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1118
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).processErrorParcel TeradataConnection.go:1181
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*TeradataRows).processResponseBundle TeradataRows.go:1415
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*TeradataRows).executeSQLRequest TeradataRows.go:521
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataRows TeradataRows.go:388
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataStatement).QueryContext TeradataStatement.go:122
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).QueryContext TeradataConnection.go:2044
 at database/sql.ctxDriverQuery ctxutil.go:48
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC.func1 sql.go:1464
 at database/sql.withLock sql.go:3032
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC sql.go:1459
 at database/sql.(*Conn).QueryContext sql.go:1701
 at main.goCreateRows goside.go:653
 at main._cgoexpwrap_1fc37444973b_goCreateRows _cgo_gotypes.go:357
 at runtime.call64 asm_amd64.s:574
 at runtime.cgocallbackg1 cgocall.go:316
 at runtime.cgocallbackg cgocall.go:194
 at runtime.cgocallback_gofunc asm_amd64.s:826
 at runtime.goexit asm_amd64.s:2361
[SQL: SELECT tablename 
FROM dbc.tablesvx 
WHERE DatabaseName (NOT CASESPECIFIC) = CAST(TRANSLATE(? USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN) as VARCHAR(128)) (NOT CASESPECIFIC) AND TableName=? AND TableKind (NOT CASESPECIFIC) IN ('O' (NOT CASESPECIFIC), 'Q' (NOT CASESPECIFIC), 'T' (NOT CASESPECIFIC))]
[parameters: ('pm', 'versionInfo')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

It's as if the library sends to the Teradata server a malformed query ... is that plausible? What can I do about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you also posted this question to the Teradata Community forum, and someone from the right team will be replying there.

The error that you got would occur if you are trying to use teradataml with an older version of the Teradata Database. What database version are you using?

Please note that teradataml requires Teradata SQL Engine 16.20 or later.

Comment: I am using ancient version 15 ... unfortunately